# Receiving non-ascii emails with App Engine Python results in strange character encoding

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email, encoding, ascii

I'm receiving emails with the Google App Engine Python and storing those in the datastore.

```
class LogSenderHandler(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, mail_message):
        logging.info("Received a message from: " + mail_message.sender)
```

When I receive an email from an ASCII address, everything works fine:

**Me [me@gmail.com]** is stored as **Me [me@gmail.com]**

However, if the sender values contains non-ascii chars, the data value stored looks like this:

**Mr Kröber [mr.kroeber@gmail.com]** is stored as **=?ISO-8859-1?Q?Mr_Kr=F6ber?= [mr.kroeber@gmail.com]**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The subject is encoded according to [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047.html). See the [Internationalized headers](http://docs.python.org/library/email.header.html) section of the [email](http://docs.python.org/library/email.html) module.

Here is an example decoding the subject to Unicode:

```
>>> s='=?ISO-8859-1?Q?Mr_Kr=F6ber?= [mr.kroeber@gmail.com]'
>>> from email.header import decode_header
>>> decode_header(s)
[('Mr Kr\xf6ber', 'iso-8859-1'), ('[mr.kroeber@gmail.com]', None)]
>>> u = u' '.join(w.decode(e or 'ascii') for w,e in decode_header(s))
>>> u
u'Mr Kr\xf6ber [mr.kroeber@gmail.com]'
>>> print u
Mr Kröber [mr.kroeber@gmail.com]
```